# What PHPUnits version should I use with Zend Framework 1.11?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

All is in the title.

I'm trying to use PHPUnits, but I am having some problems using the latest PHPUnits version with ZF 1.11.

Comment: only PHPUnit 3.5 is supportet by ZF 1.x see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8389837/131664)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit 3.5 is supported. This was also previously answered here on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389732/declaration-of-zend-test-phpunit-constraint-domqueryevaluate-should-be-compa/8389837#8389837).